# why i am getting this error "There is no row at position 0 vb.net"?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add values from **LANG_OBJ.TEXT** to `DataTableRow`.

While adding i am getting a error:

> There is no row at position 0

```
dtsaveTranslate = checkTranslateValues()
lang_id_text CType(Controls.Find("txt_id"True).FirstOrDefault(),TextB`enter code here`ox)
lang_de_text = CType(Controls.Find("txt_de", True).FirstOrDefault(), TextBox)
lang_row = dtsaveTranslate.NewRow()
lang_row("de") = lang_de_text
For Each row As DataRow In dtlang.Rows
    lang_iso = Convert.ToString(row("ISO"))
    lang_obj = CType(Controls.Find("txt_" + lang_iso, True).FirstOrDefault(), TextBox)
    Dim len As Integer = lang_obj.Text.Length
    Dim count_de As Integer = lang_de_text.Text.Length
    progress.ProgressValue = len + 1
    If Convert.ToString(row("isUbersetzen")) = "True" AndAlso lang_iso <> "de" Then
        lang_obj.Text = lanClass.GoogleApiTranslate("de", Convert.ToString(row("ISO")), lang_de_text.Text.Trim())
        lang_row(lang_iso) = lang_obj.Text
    Else
        count_txt = 0
    End If
Next
dtsaveTranslate.Rows.Add(lang_row)
```

Comment: Which line brings out the error?

Comment: After the GoogleApiTranslate translate assigning value to lang_obj.text...After that it doesn't add the value to the datarow

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that `dtLang` has rows and then try to loop them!
You need to make sure that dtLang is loaded with data. You should research why it doesn't contain any rows first. From the code above I can't see how the rows are loaded in there. Therefore, the proper check should start with:

```
If dtlang.Rows.count > 0 '<--- Added a check before looping
    For Each row As DataRow In dtlang.Rows
        lang_iso = Convert.ToString(row("ISO"))
        lang_obj = CType(Controls.Find("txt_" + lang_iso, True).FirstOrDefault(), TextBox)
        Dim len As Integer = lang_obj.Text.Length
        Dim count_de As Integer = lang_de_text.Text.Length
        progress.ProgressValue = len + 1
        If Convert.ToString(row("isUbersetzen")) = "True" AndAlso lang_iso <> "de" Then
            lang_obj.Text = lanClass.GoogleApiTranslate("de", Convert.ToString(row("ISO")), lang_de_text.Text.Trim())
            lang_row(lang_iso) = lang_obj.Text
        Else
            count_txt = 0
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: I don't think this will make any difference, as the `for` loop can handle there being 0 rows, and `dtlang` is never accessed within the loop.